# ASP Writing Values from Textbox to Textfile

Tags: vb.net, asp-classic, textarea, writetofile

I have a textarea (id=**output2**) that has a list of numbers in it. I have ASP code that writes data to a text file and it works if I specify the text.

Code to Write to Text File:

```
<%
function WriteToFile(FileName, Contents, Append)
on error resume next

if Append = true then
   iMode = 8
else 
   iMode = 2
end if
set oFs = server.createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set oTextFile = oFs.OpenTextFile(FileName, iMode, True)
oTextFile.Write Contents
oTextFile.Close
set oTextFile = nothing
set oFS = nothing

end function

%>
```

Then this code overwrites the file and inserts the data AND WORKS:

```
<%
WriteToFile "C:\INSTALL\Test1.txt", "Why is this so difficult??", False
%>
```

But yet if I leave the first code alone and try to get dynamic data such as from a textarea field it fails with no error. Doesn't even touch the text file. I tried many many ways... here are five that FAILED:

1:

```
<%
WriteToFile "C:\INSTALL\Test1.txt", Document.getElementById("output2"), False
%>
```

2:

```
<%
dim texttoinsert
texttoinsert = Document.getElementById("output2")
WriteToFile "C:\INSTALL\Test1.txt", texttoinsert, False
%>
```

3:

```
<%
WriteToFile "C:\INSTALL\Test1.txt", Response.Write(Document.getElementById("output2")), False
%>
```

4:

```
<%
dim texttoinsert
texttoinsert = "Starting to hate this"
WriteToFile "C:\INSTALL\Test1.txt", texttoinsert, False
%>
```

5:

```
<%
dim texttoinsert
texttoinsert = "Definitely hate this"
WriteToFile "C:\INSTALL\Test1.txt", Response.Write(texttoinsert), False
%>
```

I even did some VBscript that was able to tap into the Document.getElementById but I couldn't figure out how to get it to go into the ASP code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

document.getElementByID doesn't have any meaning in server-side code. You have to submit a form to pass data to  function page and then use it like this:

**html page:**

```
<form action="myfunction.asp">
<input name="texttoinsert">
<input type="submit" value="write data">
</form>
```

**myfunction.asp**

```
<%
function WriteToFile(FileName, Contents, Append)
 on error resume next
 if Append = "true" then
    iMode = 8
 else 
    iMode = 2
 end if
 set oFs = server.createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 set oTextFile = oFs.OpenTextFile(FileName, iMode, True)
 oTextFile.Write Contents
 oTextFile.Close
 set oTextFile = nothing
 set oFS = nothing
end function

texttoinsert = request("texttoinsert")
WriteToFile "C:\INSTALL\Test1.txt", texttoinsert, False
%>
```

Comment: Thank you again Ali. The reason I was trying it this way was to avoid submitting the form until I had the data in place and parsed for an INSERT RECORD. Is there a way to change this from Server Side to Client Side and still be able to write to a text file or does Client-Side forbid that?

Comment: Writing to a server file has no meaning to run client side. You can just simulate this using jquery ajax to retrieve data from input field but passing data to another page that writes received data to a server file.

Answer (score 0):

Response.write is unnecessary when passing a variable to a function.

```
<%dim texttoinsert
texttoinsert = "Definitely hate this"
WriteToFile "C:\INSTALL\Test1.txt", texttoinsert, False
%>
```

Comment: Thanks WorkSmarter. I was desperate trying anything. :-)